# How can I simultaneously collapse all files in Phabricator's Differential?

Tags: phabricator

When I am viewing a large code review in Differential, the page lags a lot unless I keep most of the files collapsed.

Unfortunately, the only way I could find to collapse all the files is to use the keyboard shortcuts for next file, and collapse repeatedly, once for each file.

Is it possible to collapse all files in relatively few clicks or keys?

On a related note, is it possible to default all diffs above a certain size to collapse all files?

Comment: I've also encountered this and wonder whether there's a way to set all files collapsed by default...

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar issues and haven't found a good solution yet, so I wrote JavaScript that would go through and manually click the 'Collapse File' for each file in the diff on the page. I saved it as a browser bookmark for convenience (just copy/paste this code as a new bookmark in your browser). Hopefully this'll help you too, OP

```
javascript:(() => {
    function collapseFiles() {
        function clickCollapseFileViewOption() {
            var viewOptionsHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("phabricator-action-view-item"),
                viewOptionsArr = [].slice.call(viewOptionsHTMLCollection);
            viewOptionsArr.find(viewOption => viewOption.text === 'Collapse File').click();
        }

        var buttonDivsHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("differential-changeset-buttons"),
            buttonDivsArr = [].slice.call(buttonDivsHTMLCollection),
            buttonAnchorsArr_unflattened = buttonDivsArr.map(buttonDiv => [].slice.call(buttonDiv.getElementsByTagName("a"))),
            buttonAnchorsArr = [].concat.apply([], buttonAnchorsArr_unflattened);
        buttonAnchorsArr.forEach((buttonAnchor, index) => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                this.click();
                clickCollapseFileViewOption();
            }.bind(buttonAnchor), 250 * index);
        });
    }
    collapseFiles();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is globally treat the files of certain types as automatically generated. checkout differential.generated-paths setting you use a regexp to set files that match that pattern as auto-generated and therefore collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

May be slightly late, but these methods use Phabricators changeset class to collapse and expand all of the changesets.

```js
collapseAllChangelistSets() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.differential-changeset').forEach(function(node) {
    let set = JX.DiffChangeset.getForNode(node);
    if (set.isVisible()) {
      try {
        set.toggleVisibility();
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn('could\'t collapse ' + set._ref);
      }
    }
  });
}

expandAllChangelistSets() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.differential-changeset').forEach(function(node) {
    let set = JX.DiffChangeset.getForNode(node);
    if (!set.isVisible()) {
      try {
        set.toggleVisibility();
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn('could\'t expand ' + set._ref);
      }
    }
  });
}
```